# How can I get the apk file of an app downloaded from Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store

I want to get the apk file of an app downloaded from Google Play. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the app from Play Store and use Astro File Manager to backup apps. From backup directory, you can get APK files of the installed app.

Answer (score 2):

Another option, which works to get the APK of any installed app, is to get it from `/data/app/` (or `/system/app/`) using a file browser or terminal, etc.  You'll need root to do that on the device though; it's easier just to use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) in that case.

Without root: From your PC you can use `adb pull` for some locations.  [Helium](http://www.clockworkmod.com/carbon) automates this.